# node-gyp-build not found when Deploying web3 App to heroku

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku, web3js, node-gyp

I'm attempting to deploy a web3 application to heroku, but while building the npm dependencies, I get the following error:

```
remote: sh: 1: node-gyp-build: not found
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                  
remote: npm ERR! syscall spawn                                                                                                    
remote: npm ERR! file sh                                                                                                          
remote: npm ERR! errno ENOENT                                                                                                     
remote: npm ERR! bufferutil@4.0.3 install: `node-gyp-build`                                                                       
remote: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT                                                                                                     
remote: npm ERR!                                                                                                                  
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@4.0.3 install script.
```

I believe this is because of the web3@1.3.6 dependency I am adding. If I leave this out of the npm dependencies in my `package.json` file, the deploy works successfully.

If I ssh into a console, I'm able to run `npm install -g web3@1.3.6` and that is also successful. I've also tried adding node-gyp, node-gyp-build, and bufferutil as explicit dependencies in the package.json file. I'm using

`node 14.17.0`
`npm 6.14.13`
`python 3.9.5`

Below is my full `package.json` file

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.0",
    "npm": "6.14.13"
  },
  "repository": {},
  "description": " ",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "postcss": "8.1.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "phoenix": "file:../deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:../deps/phoenix_html",
    "phoenix_live_view": "file:../deps/phoenix_live_view",
    "topbar": "^0.1.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
    "cropperjs": "1.5.12",
    "eth-sig-util": "^1.4.2",
    "jquery-cropper": "1.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "hard-source-webpack-plugin": "^0.13.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "web3": "1.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
}
```